проблемы линковки элементов gstreamer
Пишу программу на с++ для захвата экрана и предачи потока по udp, использую api GStreamer. Столкнулся с проблемой линковки элементов(я так думаю), кто-то знает, как понять где проблема?
static void on_pad_added (GstElement *element, GstPad *pad, gpointer data)
{
  GstPad *sinkpad;
  GstElement *decoder = (GstElement *) data;

  /* We can now link this pad with the sink pad */
  g_print ("Dynamic pad created, linking demuxer/decoder\n");

  sinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad (decoder, "sink");

  gst_pad_link (pad, sinkpad);

  gst_object_unref (sinkpad);
}

void sendVideo(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GstElement *pipeline, *source, *sink, *videoscale, *videoconvert, *x264enc, *rtph264pay;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  GstStateChangeReturn ret;

  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  source = gst_element_factory_make ("ximagesrc", "source");
  sink = gst_element_factory_make ("udpsink", "sink");
  videoscale = gst_element_factory_make ("videoscale", "videoscale");
  videoconvert = gst_element_factory_make ("videoconvert", "videoconvert");
  x264enc = gst_element_factory_make ("x264enc", "x264enc");
  rtph264pay = gst_element_factory_make ("rtph264pay", "rtph264pay");
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");
  // g_object_set(source, "startx", 1920, NULL);
  // g_object_set(source, "endx", 3839, NULL);
  g_object_set(x264enc, "tune", 0x00000004, NULL);
  g_object_set(x264enc, "bitrate", 1000, NULL);
  g_object_set(x264enc, "speed-preset", 2, NULL);
  // g_object_set(sink, "host", "127.0.0.1", NULL);
  // g_object_set(sink, "port", 5005, NULL);

  if (!pipeline || !source || !sink || !videoscale || !videoconvert || !x264enc || !rtph264pay) {
    g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    return;
  }

  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, videoscale, videoconvert, x264enc, rtph264pay, sink, NULL);
  // if (gst_element_link_many (source, videoscale, rtph264pay, sink) != TRUE) {
  //   g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
  //   gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  //   return;
  // }

  gst_element_link(source, videoscale);
  gst_element_link(videoscale, videoconvert);
  gst_element_link(videoconvert, x264enc);
  gst_element_link(x264enc, rtph264pay);
  gst_element_link(rtph264pay, sink);

  // g_signal_connect (source, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), videoscale);
  // g_signal_connect (videoscale, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), rtph264pay);
  // g_signal_connect (rtph264pay, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), sink);

  ret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
    return;
  }
  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg =
      gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
      static_cast<GstMessageType>(GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS));

  /* Parse message */
  if (msg != NULL) {
    GError *err;
    gchar *debug_info;

    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
      case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
        gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
      g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n",
          GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
      g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n",
          debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
      g_clear_error (&err);
      g_free (debug_info);
      break;
      case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
        g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
      break;
      default:
        /* We should not reach here because we only asked for ERRORs and EOS */
          g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
      break;
    }
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  }

  /* Free resources */
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
}

использую данные элементы, так как запуская через консоль все прекрасно работает.
gst-launch-1.0 -v ximagesrc startx = 0 endx = 1920 ! video/x-raw,framerate=20/1 ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=1000 speed-preset=superfast ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000


